# iOS FCM data only message does not call messaging:didReceiveMessage

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Messaging version `5.6.0`. I am attempting to [handle a data only message in the foreground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive#handle-data-messages-in-foregrounded-apps) via Firebase Messaging on iOS 9.0 (10 if needed), but it is not calling `FIRMessagingDelegate`'s `messaging:didReceiveMessage` per the documentation. I see the message come in @ `FIRMessaging.m`'s `appDidReceiveMessage:message`, but never comes through to the delegate.

This is the snippet from the cloud function that sends data to the topic per [sending to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_topic):

```
const message = {
  data: {
    test: '123'
  }
  topic: 'example'
}
admin.messaging().send(message);
```

Did I miss something?

Update: I do receive the data if I implement application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kat at Firebase support, here is the answer.

Use legacy `sendToTopic` instead of `send`, as `send` quietly adds `content_available=1` which gets treated as APNs silent notification. Here is the updated version:

```
admin.messaging().sendToTopic('example', {
  data: {
    test: '123'
  }
});
// Always use strings for key/values in the data object.
```

Below verbatim from *Kat at Firebase support*:

How the [FCM data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) is handled would depend on your setting for [content_available](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json).

- If you have `content_available = 1`, the message is sent via APNs and is treated similar as an [APNs silent notification](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2Fusernotifications%2Fsetting_up_a_remote_notification_server%2Fpushing_updates_to_your_app_silently&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNG0A2PfjQpcGys0o0yBF42KrQQb2Q). This is [handled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive#handle_messages_received_through_the_apns_interface) in the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` callback when the app is running in foreground or background (i.e. not killed). See [this related StackOverflow post](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F36694963%2Fwhat-is-silent-push-notification-when-does-the-device-receive-it&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHlEBoBAffWIKhwoGfpH2oKTQkobg) for more information.
- Without content_available, the message is sent via FCM direct channel. This only handled in the messaging:didReceiveMessage: when app is in foreground.

Note that messages sent via the Admin SDK's send() method uses the [FCM HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) which have content_available=1 by default, so they are always sent via APNs. If you want to configure the content_available field, you'll need to use the Admin SDK's sendToDevice() method which uses the [legacy protocols](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/legacy-fcm).

In addition, here is the list of [legacy protocols](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/legacy-fcm).