# IOS FCM unreceived data message

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send custom data messages to iOS mobile app, I did not receive any messages if the payload is being like this :

```
{
content_available: true,

data : {
    title   : message_title,
    body    : message_body, 
       }
}
```

but I receive the notification if I add payload like that :

```
{
content_available: true,
notification : {
    title   : message_title,
    body    : message_body,         
 },
data : {
    title   : message_title,
    body    : message_body, 
    }
}
```

but I don't want to send notification I want to send data message.

my appDelegate is:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    print("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState: \(applicationStateString) willPresentNotification: \(userInfo)")

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didReceiveData, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    print("[UserNotificationCenter] applicationState--: \(applicationStateString) didReceiveResponse: \(userInfo)")
    completionHandler()
}
```

why did not data message work?

I found the solution in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/51954446/1747440

Answer (score 0):

```
 Messaging.messaging().delegate = self  

Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
```

// call this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, then check if token is coming or not

// print(deviceToken)

// if still no token is there then you have to make sure that APNS certificate you have in your key chain must be in FireBase cloud messaging setting, apart from that your code seems fine only issue will arise in backend setting, that how you have configured your app on firebase.

[Firebase APNS cer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EvE6.png)

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding, if I put notification tag in my payload, it works fine.